# How do I solve LSTM error on predict functions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

This is the code attached below. I'm trying to run it and am getting this error below. Need help resolving it. Graph is defined as the variable name.

```
graph = Sequential()
graph.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, input_shape = (60, 1)))
graph.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=False))
graph.add(Dense(25))
graph.add(Dense(1))

graph.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
graph.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=1, epochs=1)
```

```
test_data = train_data[training_data_length - 60: , : ]
x_test = []
y_test =  dataset[training_data_length : , : ]
for i in range(60,len(test_data)):
    x_test.append(test_data[i-60:i,0])
x_test = np.array(x_test)
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0],x_test.shape[0],1))
predictions = graph.predict(x_test)
predictions = transfer.inverse_transform(predictions)
```

Getting this error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-4624ea9a4af1> in <module>()
      6 x_test = np.array(x_test)
      7 x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0],x_test.shape[0],1))
----> 8 predictions = graph.predict(x_test)
      9 predictions = transfer.inverse_transform(predictions)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1995             callbacks.on_predict_batch_end(end_step, {'outputs': batch_outputs})
   1996       if batch_outputs is None:
-> 1997         raise ValueError('Unexpected result of `predict_function` '
   1998                          '(Empty batch_outputs). Please use '
   1999                          '`Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or '

ValueError: Unexpected result of `predict_function` (Empty batch_outputs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.
```

Comment: Please add more code to your question, since it is impossible to what `graph` is, for example. Also as a first fix, have you tried what the error log is telling you (`tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)`)?

Comment: I added more code as you stated, I tried to run it and it doesn't work

Comment: Please print out, what shape `x_test` has before putting it into `graph.predict()`

Comment: I'm a bit lost by what you mean? Do you mean put a print statement like print(x_test)?

Comment: `print(x_test)` and `print(x_test.shape)`

Comment: I tried putting that statement in, before the `graph. predict()`, and the same error has still appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Your `test_data` always have length of 60 as per your construction

```
test_data = train_data[training_data_length - 60: , : ]
```

So, your `for` loop is never carried out as it is always equal to `for i in range(60,60)`. Consequently, `x_test` remains `[]` and causes the error.

I'm guessing that you want to construct a set of length-60 series, each offset the next by 1 timestep. In that case, the test data should've been constructed as

```
for i in range(60,len(train_data)):
    x_test.append(train_data[i-60:i,0])
```

Also, your `np.reshape` usage seems wrong. The number of elements after reshape will be `x_test.shape[0] * x_test.shape[0]`, but the original `x_test` have `x_test.shape[0] * x_test.shape[1]`, so unless `x_test.shape[0] == x_test.shape[1]`, you'll always get an error. You don't need reshape anyway, as your `x_test` should've already been in the right shape.